# executing ssis package from a computer where integration services in not installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ssis

I am using following line of code in a web application to execute a package which resides on other server where integration service is installed.But I am unable to execute it on application server.

```
        string pkgLocation;
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;

        pkgLocation = @"\\hddlntd6021985\ssis\Package1.dtsx";

        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

       Response.Write(pkgResults.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a problem to run packages remotely. You've got several opportunities but neither of them may work perfectly. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx) article explains your opportunities and pros and cons of each. What you've tried to do is in the first point.

Another way can be use of PowerShell Remoting explained in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/10/11/remote-ssis-package-execution-with-powershell-2-0.aspx) article. In one of my projects I runned remotely a package this way, but at the and the IT did not allowed to use it because of their security policy. (PowerShell Remoting opens ports 5985 and 5986) I think it is a simple solution. More simple than developing a service on the database server. So if you are allowed to open these ports on database server, you may consider using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run SSIS packages without installing SSIS. However, you can [execute a package remotely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx) (note the first sentence on that page) so your application server can still execute a package on the SSIS server.

Comment: Actually the problem is that my application is installed on application server.My database and package is located at db server.Now i have to find a way through which my application executes ssis packages without installing integration services here.

Comment: Yes, that is what I understood. How does my answer not apply to your situation?

Comment: if i am creating a service on db server,I have to install iis to host that service on dbserver which is not acceptable by client.

Comment: What about using a scheduled job instead of a service? Or buy another MSSQL license and install SSIS on the application server? In the end, if your client (or you!) requires certain tools, they must be prepared to pay both the financial and technical costs of using them.